# What are partitioned tables used for in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I know that partitioned tables are used for distributing load horizontally, but what are their exact uses? Can anybody explain to me with a simple example?

Comment: Check on google. There are nice answers.

Comment: Additionally, [Hive Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual) is a good place to learn as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitioning allows Hive to access a subset of your data without having to read all of it.  Here's a concrete example of why that could be useful. To make this easy to understand I'm being very reductive in my explanations, I recommend reading up on Hive partitions elsewhere if you want more than the surface level understanding I'm trying to provide.

You are receiving time stamped data at a rate of `~1TB` per day. You have data going back 100 days for a total data load of `~100TB`. Very often, you want to aggregate some data over the past 10 days. Without partitioning, you will have to read in all `100TB` of data even though most of it will be ignored by Hive anyway because it does not match your filter on date (which is in your WHERE clause). If you partition by date, Hive will split the data into chunks for each day, each with `~1TBGB`. Hive looks at your WHERE clause and figures out in advance which partitions will pass the filter and only process that data. In this case, we would only have to look at `10TB` of data which will be a huge reduction of our use of cluster resources and increase in the job completion time. And now even once we have 1000 days of data totaling `1PB` we will still only have to look at `10TB` of data.

In practice, it is very common for many Hive queries to only care about a well defined subset of your total data volume. Think about which columns you often specify a range (or single specific value) for in WHERE clause. You can even partition on multiple columns. For example if we had a color column with 10 possible colors and each color was responsible for about 100GB of data per day we might additionally partition on color. Then if we only care about `red` data for the past 10 days, we only have to process `1TB` of data.

Be careful not to overdo partitioning though. From my date example you might think that if partitioning on date is good, partitioning on a timestamp down to the second is better. This would in theory allow you to only pull in exactly the rows you care about. If you do this, however, your partitions will end up being very small and Hive does not do well working with very small files. The same concerns exist for partitioning on too many columns. Another thing to watch is how well distributed your data is on the columns you are partitioning on. If 90% of your data has the color `black`, 9% has the color `red`, and the remaining 1% is split among the other 8 colors then you will have some massive and some tiny partitions which is not ideal.

Partitioning also has some other benefits like reducing the file size of your underlying data. This is achieved by taking that column out of the file that backs the table and putting the value of that column in the folder that holds the partition.

From reading your question, it seemed like you were looking for an answer about partitioned tables. Managed vs external tables is an entirely separate issue which should get its own question.

Answer (score 0):

Hive managed tables are completely managed by hive, Hive creates a copy of table(data source) in their own data warehouse and at time of removing hive it self is responsible of removing this file from warehouse.In counter of managed table,
external table directly are created by hive using External keyword at the time of table creation and does not copy any data in warehouse. During drop table data would remain intact.

Comment: Question is about partitioned tables, not external tables.